# Como detectar se uma string é um regex

Tags: php, regex

Supondo que tenho a string:

```
$regex = "/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i";
```

Existe algo nativo do php para testar se é uma regex valida?

Se não, qual seria a melhor forma de testar isso ?

Comment: Nativo seria tentar compilar a regex e verificar o erro. Agora, não nativo... você não pode validar uma regex usando regex... Teria de construir uma gramática livre de contexto para isso

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `preg_match` irá retornar um valor tipo `int` ser for válido, se a *regex* for válida mas não "casar com a string" irá retornar zero (`0`).

Agora se a regex for inválida o `preg_match` irá retornar um valor booleano ao invés de `int`, que será `false`

Então por exemplo, isto é uma regex válida com um valor (string) que "casa", irá retornar `int(1)` porque casou e a regex é valida:

```
var_dump(preg_match('#^[a-z]+$#', 'abcdef'));
```

Agora assim retornará `int(0)`, a regex é valida:

```
var_dump(preg_match('#^[a-z]+$#', '100000'));
```

Agora uma regex inválida irá retornar `bool(false)`:

```
var_dump(preg_match('#^[a-z#', '100000'));
```

Mas é importante notar que ele emite um *warning*, algo como:

```
PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 5
```

Mas um warning não é necessáriamente um erro, seria mais para um aviso, em servidores de produção este tipo de mensagem geralmente é desligada (`display_errors=off`), ainda aparecem no arquivo de log, mas não afetam a execução do script, que irá correr normalmente até o final.

Se quiser fazer realmente um teste especifico, acaso esteja criando uma coleção de regex, por exemplo você esta criando um sistema que a pessoa cadastra os proprios validadores customizados, então você pode criar um teste assim:

```
/**
 * @param string $regex
 * @return bool
 */
function validate_regex($regex)
{
     return preg_match($regex, '') !== false;
}
```

E o uso fica assim:

```
validate_regex('/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i'); //Retorna TRUE
validate_regex('/[^a-z_\-0-9/i'); //Retorna FALSE
```

Comment: muito bem explicado +1.